# why Delegate Methods for CurrentLotion(CLLocationManager) is not called in iOS4.0?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am using iPhone sdk 4.0.I have used below code for taking Current location but it's delegate methods is not called Automatically...My code is given below:

in `.hfile`

i have import

`CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h`

also delegate

`CLLocationManagerDelegate`

`CLLocationManager *locationManager;`

in `.mfile`

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

but i don't get the current location for that......My Delegate Method is which is not called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

}
```

Comment: Try installing  onto iphone ,as the code looks ok .

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me. Did you also tried to run this code on a real iPhone? Simulator is not always responding to location manager updates. 
There is also another important delegate method you should add to your .m file:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

This one will be called in case something goes wrong. For instance the location manager failed to localize your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same problem. All the code looks ok but the delegate method was not called.

I closed the simulator completely. When I rerun the app, delegate method was called.